# How to convert the terminal output and input into an electron app gui

Tags: javascript, python, html, node.js, electron

Here's my code:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call("ssh santiago@192.168.56.101", shell=True)
```

I'm building an electronjs app and I want to use python with it as I'm more familiar with it. I want to have a page that has an interactive terminal that displays on the window of the program. I have created a script in python that would allow you to do this in the terminal console however how can I use this code with electron to make a friendly gui terminal that you could use like any other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) the python app as a child process. Depending on your `BrowserWindow` configuration you may be able to do that directly from the renderer process (with `nodeIntegration` or `electron.remote`, both are generally discouraged), or you may have to use IPC and/or `ContextBridge` to pass messages from and to the spawned app to and from the `BrowserWindow`.

You can spawn the python app like this:

```js
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const pythonApp = spawn('python', ['path/to/app.py', arg1, arg2, ...]);

pythonApp.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  // stdout from the python app
});

// stdin to the python app
pythonApp.stdin.write('...')
```

If you're willing to use `nodeIntegration` then that's basically it, otherwise you will need [ipcMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main), [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) and optionally, for extra security, [ContextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in electron the page is displayed using html. How would I got about about doing that?

Comment: Pure HTML is static, you need JavaScript to make it interactive. You would need to use JavaScript to receive messages from the python process and display them on the webpage, by adding new HTML elements or editing existing ones. How to do that exactly is a very broad question. Your best bet would probably be looking into a basic front end dev course or tutorial.

Comment: Do you have discord? It will be easier to chat add me: username.s.v
#7273